# Husky and Git Hooks Guards not respected in IDEs

Tags: reactjs, git, visual-studio-code, githooks, husky

I have `husky` and `lint-staged` setup in a repository I am a main contributor to, and these guards consist of ensuring correct `commitlint` messages, proper branch naming patterns, and checking for linting errors on all commits.

This all works great when creating/committing/pushing branches from the command line, but when using any IDE's integrated Git UI, the checks are completely ignored, and anything can make it to the repo (*incorrect commit messages, incorrect branch names, linting errors, etc.*). Not sure why, nor do I know how to avoid this.

Here are some of the relevant pieces of code that is within this web of guards (*obviously with irrelevant code omitted for clarity*):

`package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
  "lint": "eslint app/"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@commitlint/cli": "^16.2.3",
  "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^16.2.1",
  "enforce-branch-name": "^1.0.1"
},

...

"husky": {
  "hooks": {
    "commit-msg": "commitlint -E HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS",
    "pre-push": "enforce-branch-name '^(branch-name-regex-rules)$'"
  }
},
"lint-staged": {
  "*.js": "npm run lint"
}
```

And then I have my `.husky` folder at the project root, with my `commit-msg`, `pre-commit`, and `pre-push` hook scripts:

`commit-msg`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npx --no -- commitlint --edit $1
```

`pre-commit`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npx lint-staged
```

`pre-push`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
LC_ALL=C

local_branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
valid_branch_regex="^(branch-name-regex-rules)$"
message="Error message for incorrect branch naming"

if [[ ! $local_branch =~ $valid_branch_regex ]]
then
  echo "$message"
  exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

I think that should cover all the relevant code pieces that I have. Like I said, when using the command line to make commits and push branches to the remote, these rules come into play and work, informing developers of incorrect patterns.

But any developer that uses like, VSCode's integrated Git feature to commit and/or push (*or even just stage the files*), none of the guards work, and it's as if someone just added `--no-verify` to a command line Git declaration to force the commit/push despite failing hooks/guards.

Not sure what I need to do to get `husky` and `lint-staged` to work appropriately for any method of staging files, making commits, branch naming, etc. etc.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, or can point me somewhere that might explain what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: for vscode, you can see the git commands executed by the IDE : in the terminal view (`View > Terminal`) select the `Output` tab, then `Log (Git)` in the dropdown in the top right corner.

Comment: Yep, I'm aware of that. This doesn't really pertain to my question tho.

Comment: When you commit : do you see `git commit -n` or `git commit --no-verify` in the Log output ?

Comment: still focusing on the "commit" action: from my PC using VSCode : if I exit with non-zero code from pre-commit hook, VSCode does block the commit and shows me the stdout/stderr in a dialog. I'm trying to see what is different wrt your setup.

Comment: your pre-commit hook also involves loading a whole lot of nodejs code, which may be affected by the environment in which your commands are executed. To debug your script's traces when executed through vscode, you may redirect stdout and stderr to files on disk : `exec 2>/tmp/pre-commit-log; exec 1>/tmp/pre-commit-log`, and inspect things like `env`, `which npx`, `set -x`, turn on verbose logging in husky ...

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the tips! Let me do some more digging around this information....